# Inserir dados ao criar tabela SQLite

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Em meu banco de dados tenho uma tabela Estado e Cidades, gostaria de inserir esses dados assim que o app for instalado, ou seja ao criar o banco esses registros ja serem inseridos nas tabelas de uma vez. Fiz o seguinte codigo porem está inserindo apenas o primeiro Estado

```
public class BancoDados extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public static final String NOME_BANCO = "carona";
private static final int VERSAO_BANCO = 1;

public BancoDados(Context context) {
    super(context, NOME_BANCO, null, VERSAO_BANCO);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(SQL_ESTADO);
    db.execSQL(SQL_LISTA_ESTADOS);

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}

String SQL_ESTADO = "CREATE TABLE [Estado](\n" +
        "[EstadoId] [INT] NOT NULL,\n" +
        "[Sigla] [char](2) NOT NULL,\n" +
        "CONSTRAINT [PK_Estado] PRIMARY KEY ([EstadoId])\n" +
        ");";


String SQL_LISTA_ESTADOS = "INSERT INTO [Estado] ([EstadoId],[Sigla]) VALUES (1,'AC');\n"+
        "INSERT INTO [Estado] ([EstadoId],[Sigla]) VALUES (2,'AL'); " +
        "INSERT INTO [Estado] ([EstadoId],[Sigla]) VALUES (3,'AM'); " +
        "INSERT INTO [Estado] ([EstadoId],[Sigla]) VALUES (4,'AP'); " +
        "INSERT INTO [Estado] ([EstadoId],[Sigla]) VALUES (5,'BA'); " +
        "INSERT INTO [Estado] ([EstadoId],[Sigla]) VALUES (6,'CE'); " +
        "INSERT INTO [Estado] ([EstadoId],[Sigla]) VALUES (7,'DF'); " +
        "INSERT INTO [Estado] ([EstadoId],[Sigla]) VALUES (8,'ES'); " +
        "INSERT INTO [Estado] ([EstadoId],[Sigla]) VALUES (9,'GO');  +
        "INSERT INTO [Estado] ([EstadoId],[Sigla]) VALUES (10,'MA');" +
        "INSERT INTO [Estado] ([EstadoId],[Sigla]) VALUES (11,'MG');" +
        "INSERT INTO [Estado] ([EstadoId],[Sigla]) VALUES (12,'MS');" +
        "INSERT INTO [Estado] ([EstadoId],[Sigla]) VALUES (13,'MT');" +
        "INSERT INTO [Estado] ([EstadoId],[Sigla]) VALUES (14,'PA');" +
        "INSERT INTO [Estado] ([EstadoId],[Sigla]) VALUES (15,'PB');" +
        "INSERT INTO [Estado] ([EstadoId],[Sigla]) VALUES (16,'PE');" +
        "INSERT INTO [Estado] ([EstadoId],[Sigla]) VALUES (17,'PI');" +
        "INSERT INTO [Estado] ([EstadoId],[Sigla]) VALUES (18,'PR');" +
        "INSERT INTO [Estado] ([EstadoId],[Sigla]) VALUES (19,'RJ');" +
        "INSERT INTO [Estado] ([EstadoId],[Sigla]) VALUES (20,'RN');" +
        "INSERT INTO [Estado] ([EstadoId],[Sigla]) VALUES (21,'RO');" +
        "INSERT INTO [Estado] ([EstadoId],[Sigla]) VALUES (22,'RR');" +
        "INSERT INTO [Estado] ([EstadoId],[Sigla]) VALUES (23,'RS');" +
        "INSERT INTO [Estado] ([EstadoId],[Sigla]) VALUES (24,'SC');" +
        "INSERT INTO [Estado] ([EstadoId],[Sigla]) VALUES (25,'SE');" +
        "INSERT INTO [Estado] ([EstadoId],[Sigla]) VALUES (26,'SP');" +
        "INSERT INTO [Estado] ([EstadoId],[Sigla]) VALUES (27,'TO');";
```

}

Comment: Está faltando uma aspa no final da linha que insere o registro 9. Ele chega a rodar mesmo assim?

Comment: Infelizmente não é. Retirei até o \n no registro 1. Ainda continua inserindo apenas o primeiro estado. Esta rodando porem so insere o primeiro.

Answer (score 1):

Se a sua versão do SQLite é maior ou igual à 3.7.11 você pode inserir várias linhas no mesmo insert, [conforme documentação](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html). Tente substituindo sua string SQL por isto:

```
String SQL_LISTA_ESTADOS = "INSERT INTO [Estado] ([EstadoId],[Sigla]) VALUES " +
        "(1,'AC'), " +
        "(2,'AL'), " +
        "(3,'AM'), " +
        "(4,'AP'), " +
        "(5,'BA'), " +
        "(6,'CE'), " +
        "(7,'DF'), " +
        "(8,'ES'), " +
        "(9,'GO'), " +
        "(10,'MA')," +
        "(11,'MG')," +
        "(12,'MS')," +
        "(13,'MT')," +
        "(14,'PA')," +
        "(15,'PB')," +
        "(16,'PE')," +
        "(17,'PI')," +
        "(18,'PR')," +
        "(19,'RJ')," +
        "(20,'RN')," +
        "(21,'RO')," +
        "(22,'RR')," +
        "(23,'RS')," +
        "(24,'SC')," +
        "(25,'SE')," +
        "(26,'SP')," +
        "(27,'TO');";
```

Answer (score 1):

pra que voce precisa usar uma tabela para isso se esses dados são sempre estáticos, sendo assim, usa um array estados e pronto, dai ficaria assim oO:

```
String [][] Estados = new String[][] {
    {"1","AC"},
    {"2","AL"},
    {"3","AM"},
    {"4","AP"},
    {"5","BA"},
    {"6","CE"},
    {"7","DF"},
    {"8","ES"},
    {"9","GO"},
    {"10","MA"},
    {"11","MG"},
    {"12","MS"},
    {"13","MT"},
    {"14","PA"},
    {"15","PB"},
    {"16","PE"},
    {"17","PI"},
    {"18","PR"},
    {"19","RJ"},
    {"20","RN"},
    {"21","RO"},
    {"22","RR"},
    {"23","RS"},
    {"24","SC"},
    {"25","SE"},
    {"26","SP"},
    {"27","TO"}
    };
```

dai você pega ele usando:

```
int mEstId = Integer.parseInt(Estados[10][0]); // == 9
String mEstSg = Estados[10][1]; // == "GO"
```

voce pode também usar num loop para montar sua query e inserir na tabela, algo tipo:

```
public void insereNaTabela() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String sql = NULL;
    for (int i=0;i<Estados.lenght;i++) {
        sql = "INSERT INTO Estado (EstadoId,Sigla) VALUES ('" + Estados[i][0] + "','" + Estados[i][1] + "');";
        db.execSQL(sql);
    }
}
// especificamente insere linha a linha na tabela, isso evitaria erros
```

Lembrando que:
1 - o sqlite independe de tipos de dados, assim, tanto faz você passar 10 ou '10' para uma coluna integer vai inserir o valor 10 da mesma forma;
2 - É recomendado na documentação usar '10' para inserir valores, visto que independe do tipo de dado;
3 - você pode usar tanto o array diretamente para obter os dados que você precisa para pegar um estado ou usar o mesmo no loop para inserir na tabela caso você precise de uma relação especifica no db.
Finalmente, assim, seu código ficaria muito mais enxuto.

Saúde e Paz!